# Angular Material Checkbox Two-Way binding

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend

I have a question on how two-way binding work in Angular Material checkbox.

This is HTML template from `app.component.html`:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let data of testData">
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.isActive" (change)="handleData(data)">{{data.isActive}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the component (`app.component.ts`):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  testData: TestData[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testData = [];

    this.testData.push({
      label: 'testData1',
      isActive: false
    });

    this.testData.push({
      label: 'testData2',
      isActive: false
    });
  }

  handleData(data: TestData) {
    console.log(data.isActive);
    data.isActive = false;
  }
}

export class TestData {
  label: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

All the checkboxes are unchecked by default. When I click a checkbox for the first time, the `data` parameter in the `handleData` handler receives `true` in `data.isActive`. I set this to `false` afterwards. The corresponding labels are never changed (they are always `false`). But I also expect for a checkbox never be checked as well. But it does is checked. Why this happens?

**UPDATED**
I've just added the 'Results' section that contains checkboxes that reflect the ones above:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let data of testData">
      <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.isActive" (change)="handleData(data)">{{data.isActive}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

<div>
  <div *ngFor="let data of testData">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.isActive" (change)="handleData(data)">{{data.isActive}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unlike their neighbours above they are never checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value may be reset too quickly, when Angular has not completed the change detection cycle triggered by the click. It works if we reset the value asynchronously with `setTimeout` (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-zvf1bq)):

```
handleData(data: TestData) {
  console.log(data.isActive);
  setTimeout(() => {
    data.isActive = false;
  });
}
```

or if we call `ChangeDetectofRef.detectChanges()` before resetting the value (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-drhcde)):

```
handleData(data: TestData) {
  console.log(data.isActive);
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  data.isActive = false;
}
```

Comment: It work with my example too. Is it possible, for example, to subscribe to angular change detector so as not to be dependant on a timeout?

Comment: I tried with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` first but it does not appear to work. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-cvlngr).

Comment: Oh but I found that it does work if we call it before resetting the value. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are the greatest!